# Post date format and select date format from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a textbox that displays the current date in format: `d-m-Y`

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>"/>
```

When I save this the date will written to my database like: `Y-m-d`. For example: the current date is: 02-06-2016. My script writes this to the database as: 2002-06-16.

I am using the following code to save the data to my database:

```
<?php
 session_start(); 

 $correct = true;

 $date = $_POST['date'] ;

 if($correct){
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');

  $query = "INSERT INTO table(date) VALUES (?)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array($date));

  header('Location: ./index.php');  
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Error";
 }
?>
```

What do I need to change in my code so it will post it like: 2016-06-02 `Y-m-d` or 02-06-2016 `d-m-Y`?

If `d-m-Y` is not possible, how can show the data that is written like `Y-m-d` in the database show as format `d-m-Y` in my php script?

**Edit:**

For selecting the date I use:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$sql = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date']));

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td>";
     }                   
} else {
                      echo "<p> </p>";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: ,change the post data format as like database format using strtotime

Comment: And how can I call this so it will show d-m-Y on my php page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = $_POST['date'] ;

$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

To show date in `d-m-Y` format in HTML page, again convert it into

`$date = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date']));`

[**Note**: I'm assuming your fetch array as `$row` and column as `date`.]

For more info, please have a look on [strtotime - php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

**Update Code** (As question is edited)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date'])). "</td>";
  }                   
} else {
  echo "<p> </p>";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Oke, this is working, the right date is written in the database. How can I call this so it will show `d-m-Y` on my php page

Comment: I am running a SELECT * statement `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table`.

Will it work when I write after this: `$sql = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date']));`

Comment: You have to fetch `$sql` first. Without fetching, how it is possible to write simply `sql = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date']))`. First fetch. Then, using that fetch array convert date. It's very simple. I think you are very new to it. Please post your code where you are displaying date @John